# Does invoking NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints invalidate the constraints?

Tags: ios, constraints

Do I need to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` after invoking `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints`? If so, for which cases?

Answer (score 2):

**Do I need to call setNeedsUpdateConstraints after invoking NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints?**

The short answer is No, `activateConstraints` is meant to adjust view layout based on provided constraints when they're created. In the other hand you usually use `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on animations or when layout conditions change.

About `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` the documentation says:

> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a note of the request and returns immediately. Because this method does not force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is usually better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to animate a view after modifying a constraint and animate the changes we usually call:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animation:^{
        [self.animatingView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self.animatingView layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:NULL];
```

If we use `-setNeedsLayout` instead of `-setNeedsUpdateConstraints` everything work as expected, but if we change `-layoutIfNeeded` with `-updateConstraintsIfNeeded`, the animation don't occurs.

- `-updateConstraintsIfNeeded` only update constraints so no animation occurs.
- `-setNeedsLayout` calls also `-updateContraints` method
- `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` do call
  `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` and calls `updateConstraints`

Comment: That's interesting.  So then, are there cases where invoking NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints invalidates the constraints?

Comment: yes they must, although i have tried once in which i have activated and deactivated a single constraint it was updating automatically..
also in apple documentation
Convenience method that activates each constraint in the contained array, in the same manner as setting active=YES. This is often more efficient than activating each constraint individually.